# Blender 2.9 Bevel setting

Tags: bevel

[image]

On the left object bevel applied as expected.
The vertices at the corners are connected
On the right object strange things happen on the corners.
The vertices at the corner aren't connected were they were connected without the bevel.
Same bevel setting applied to both objects.

I've created the triangle from a cone. and converted curve from mesh. The idea is to create a wire / tube model which I can print.

I followed instructions for tube modeling.

How to apply the correct settings?

Comment: It's really hard to answer generic questions like these if we don't know what you want to achieve. So... I'll just guess and assume that the vertices at the corners aren't connected.

Comment: Yes that is correct. i've created the triangle from a cone. and converted curve from mesh. The idea is to create a wire / tube model which I can print.

Comment: Hello, FYI in a curve one point can't be connected to more than 2 other points (it may physically sit on the same place, but it won't be connected), so it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do with curve objects.